# Huawei p8 or p8 Lite has problem with Keystore Encryption

Tags: android, keystore, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

Recently I migrated my application (date encryption) from using keypairgeneratorspec to use keyGenParameterSpec Api for devices API level >= 23 ...

after that my app works fine on all devices except huawei p8 and p8 lite
when user launches my app makes his phone restarts ...
I confused whats the the reason.
I do not have access to this huawei models for debugging and I tried to test my app with firebase testlab ... finally I can not figure out what happened on these models.

please help...

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer ...
the problem is keystore implementatio in huawei devices.
specially in P series e.x (P8 , P8 lite , P9 ....) and maybe few other models of huawei
which is fixed in newer models .
to fix this issue you have to set start date and end date for keyGenParameterSpec builder.

Comment: do you have any more info on this?  I think i might be seeing it too but really hard to reproduce without the phone.