# Android Keystore can't create cipher for Keystore Key

Tags: android, android-keystore, huawei-developers

I have not been able to reproduce this on any phones, only have logs from a user.  They have a HUAWEI phone and it looks like their Keystore code has been modified since none of the line numbers line up to googlesource.  It happens when trying to create a Cipher object from a Key. `Cipher.init`.  User has a HUAWEI ( Nova 3i ).  I've seen some other issues with HUAWEI: [Huawei p8 or p8 Lite has problem with Keystore Encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63791696/huawei-p8-or-p8-lite-has-problem-with-keystore-encryption)

> java.security.InvalidKeyException: Keystore operation failed
> at android.security.KeyStore.getInvalidKeyException(KeyStore.java:924)
> at android.security.KeyStore.getInvalidKeyException(KeyStore.java:949)
> at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getInvalidKeyExceptionForInit(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:54)
> at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getExceptionForCipherInit(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:89)
> at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.ensureKeystoreOperationInitialized(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:265)
> at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineInit(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:148)
> at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryTransformWithProvider(Cipher.java:2980)
> at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryCombinations(Cipher.java:2891)
> at javax.crypto.Cipher$SpiAndProviderUpdater.updateAndGetSpiAndProvider(Cipher.java:2796)
> at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:773)
> at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1288)
> at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1223)

> Caused by: android.security.KeyStoreException: Device locked
> at android.security.KeyStore.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore.java:862)

Has anyone encountered this before with HUAWEI phone or any other phones?  It looks like the key can be used at some point but then not again.  Sample of the Key generation

```
val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(ANDROID_KEYSTORE)
keyStore.load(null)
val keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(
        KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES,
        ANDROID_KEYSTORE)
val builder = KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
        keyName,
        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
    .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
    .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
keyGenerator.init(builder.build())
val key = keyGenerator.generateKey()
```